# Is it possible to redirect anonymous users from /admin to /user?

Tags: 7, users, redirection

Say I have a site called drupal.local, the user login page would be `drupal.local/user`. And the admin 'homepage' would be `drupal.local/admin`.

The problem is that lots of people seem to expect `drupal.local/admin` to lead them to the login page if they are not already logged in. Unfortunately instead of doing that, they just get:

> You are not authorized to access this page.

I guess (thinking about it) a decent solution would be to put a link to the login page in the 403 error template text - but it would be more elegant to redirect the user to /user if they weren't already logged in.

Is it possible to do such a thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you can install a module like [Redirect 403 to User Login](https://www.drupal.org/project/r4032login):

> Redirect the HTTP 403 error page to the Drupal /user/login page with an optional message that reads:
>
> > "Access denied! You must login to view this page."
>
> Also, the desired page is appended in the url query string so that, once login is successful, the user is taken directly where they were originally trying to go.

Comment: Awesome, just what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also go for [LoginToboggan](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan)

```
Provide a login form on Access Denied pages for non-logged-in (anonymous) users.
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like there's plenty of other useful things you can do with this one too :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module for this. Here is the rule you'd need for it (in [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) export format, just use copy/paste to import it in your own setup):

```
{ "rules_redirect_admin_path_to_user_path" : {
    "LABEL" : "Redirect admin path to user path",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "init" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "user_has_role" : {
          "account" : [ "site:current-user" ],
          "roles" : { "value" : { "1" : "1" } }
        }
      },
      { "text_matches" : {
          "text" : [ "site:current-page:path" ],
          "match" : "admin",
          "operation" : "starts"
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "To access this path (= /admin) you need to login first, you will be redirected automatically to  path (= /user)." } },
      { "redirect" : { "url" : user" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

This rule uses 2 Rules Conditions:

- Is this an anonymous user?
- Does the current path start with `/admin`?

Whenever such redirect actually happens (that is: both Rules Conditions are satisfied), the user will also receive an informational message like so:

> *To access this path (= `/admin`) you need to login first, you will be redirected automatically to  path (= `/user`).*

If you don't want such message to appear, then just delete the line containing `drupal_message` in the exported rule above.

Similar to the previous answers, it might require you to enable an extra contributed module ([Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)). But, as indicated by its growing popularity also, that module is probably already enabled in mostly any site (similar to the [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) module), because there are dozens of use-cases for this module).

**Note**: IMO it makes sense to perform such redirect for any path that *starts with* `/admin`. But should you rather prefer to perform such redirect only for an exact match for path `/admin` (instead of starting with such path), then simply replace the 2nd Rules Condition with this one (that is: omit the "operation" which is "starts"):

```
  { "text_matches" : {
      "text" : [ "site:current-page:path" ],
      "match" : "admin"
    }
  }
```